# What's wrong with this lasso regression implementation in R?

Tags: r, debugging, machine-learning, regression

I'm trying to code from scratch a function that estimates regression coefficients using LASSO with coordinated descent (Gauss-Seidel) and soft thresholding.

My code is the following:

```
library(MASS)
set.seed(1)
n = 200
p = 200
V = matrix(0.2, p, p)
diag(V) = 1
X = as.matrix(mvrnorm(n, mu = rep(0, p), Sigma = V))
y = X[, 1] + 0.5*X[, 2] + 0.25*X[, 3] + rnorm(n)
X = scale(X)
y = scale(y)

soft_th <- function(b, lambda){
  if (b > lambda){
    return (b - lambda)
  }
  else if (b < -lambda){
    return(b + lambda)
  }
  else {
    return (0)
  }
}

myLasso <- function(X,y, lambda=0.3,tol=1e-5,maxitr=100){
  beta_old <- rep(0,p)
  beta_new <- rep(0,p)
  for(i in 1:maxitr){
    beta_old <- beta_new
    for (j in (1:ncol(X)))
      {
      X_j <- X[,j]
      y_pred <- t(X)%*%beta_old
      rho <- t(X_j)%*%(y - y_pred + beta_old[j]*X_j)
      beta_new[j] <- soft_th(rho,0.7)
    }

    l1 <- sum(abs(beta_old-beta_new))
    print(l1)
    r <-  y - t(X)%*%beta_old

    if (l1<tol){
      print('Convergence reached')
      break
  }
  }

}
myLasso(X,y)
```

The problem that I have is that the L1 norm between beta_old and beta_new increases (a lot!) between each iteration. I'm following what is said in this post:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123672/coordinate-descent-soft-thresholding-update-operator-for-lasso/351134#351134

I think that somewhat I'm not correctly implementing the descent update rule.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was doing more research, and it seems that I didn't normalise the X matrix. After adding X <- X/norm(X,type='2') after defining X, the problem solved.

Comment: You can delete a question if you think it is not going to be useful. Alternatively you can answer your own question if you think there may be value to future viewers.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing more research, and it seems that I didn't normalise the X matrix. After adding X <- X/norm(X,type='2') after defining X, the problem solved.

Now a new problem that I have is that this new function does not replicate the results of the glmnet implementation of LASSO regression. What could it be? I got a RMSE of 0.6 with glmnet and 0.997 with my implementation. I'd love if someone could guide me in how to improve my function.

Thanks in advance.